# Interop SaveAs bypasses input file extension

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to develop an extension method which uses excel interop and converts any given input file into a new file in accord with an additional xlfileFormat input parametre.

The problem that I have found so far is that SaveAs method bypasses any arbitrary extension that I set, and sets It in accord with xlFileFormat options.

For example:

- xlFileFormat = xlCsv, fileName= foo.arbitrary => saves it as
  foo.arbitrary.csv
- xlFileFormat = xlExcel8, fileName= extensionLessFoo => saves it
  as extensionLessFoo.xls
- xlFileFormat = xlOpenWorkbook, fileName= foo.xlsx => saves it as foo.xlsx (this one is OK)

I have been able to overcome this problem by specifying random GUID-based file names, and introducing this name as a SaveAs *FileName* parametre. Later, i will read final input workbook *fullName*, and return the recently created FileInfo

I would prefer not to depend on temporary files, but allow for specifying the file name **AND** the extension. so far, nor SaveCopyAs nor SaveAs have provided me a proper solution.

---

This is the method  have been developing so far:

```
  public static FileInfo InteropConvertTo(this FileInfo inputFile, XlFileFormat format)
    {
        var outputFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "Random SaveAs File -" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var outputFile = new FileInfo(outputFileName);
        try
        {
            //creation of a new, silent application
            var hiddenApp = new Application();
            hiddenApp.Visible = false;
            hiddenApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
            hiddenApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            //adding workbook, saving as new format, closing
            var inputWorkbook = hiddenApp.Workbooks.Add(inputFile);
            inputWorkbook.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
            inputWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename: outputFileName,
                FileFormat: format , AccessMode:XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, CreateBackup: false);

            outputFile = new FileInfo(inputWorkbook.FullName);
            outputFile.IsReadOnly = false;

        xlWorkBook.Close(false);
        xlApp.Quit();
        releaseObject(hiddenApp );
        releaseObject(inputWorkbook);

        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }

        return outputFile;


    }


    private static void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            obj = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to use SaveAs forcing your own output file extension?

Comment: @Darren: Sorry, ¿could you ellaborate on that? I do not really see the relation between xlFileFormat being an enum and the extension that is added to the resulting output file.

Comment: Please note that i am concerned about the OUTPUT of the method: I am certainly aware that, in order to add or open a file into a workbook, extension is needed to allow excel recognizing its format (although I do think that MIME types could be succesfully used here)

Comment: @DarrenYoung Pretty fair question. This issue was raised when tried to save excel files as CSV with an specific file extension, which I was not able to. As for why do i need it, there is an old and grumpy application which needs the files in some pre-defined extension (I suppose it internally filters them out from the input directory). After seeing that, I was curious and decided to investigate :)